# /?wc-ajax=checkout 504 error but still taking payment

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, stripe-payments

I have created an online store with wordpress and woocommerce and linked both Paypal and stripe plugins. The paypay one has worked and is taking payment successfully but stripe is giving a 504 on every checkout but still taking the payment.

I have upped my php memory limit in the wp-config file and made sure all the details in my account are correct but I cant work out why it returns a 504 but then takes the payment straight after.

Please help!

Comment: Is the error coming from Stripe's API or from your server? This sounds like something internal to your server. You should check your Stripe developer logs for any API errors: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs If there are no errors there, the problem is on your server and you'll need to contact WordPress/WooCommerce support for help with this.

Comment: No errors coming from stripes API so im guessing its my server but no idea how to fix it